# How to check a given connection has been offloaded to network card

Tags: linux-networking, netstat, tcp-offload-engine

From what I read, some part of the tcp protocol operation can be offloaded from kernel to network card driver thanks to TOE (or GSO, LSO, LRO..).

My objective is too find if a given socket has some part of its treatment offloaded.

It seems to be governed at the interface level, we can see if offloading is allowed with

```
# ethotool -k eth0
```

However I find it difficult to see the state of a given socket, especially if ACK packet management has been offloaded

[na_netstat](http://www.uow.edu.au/~blane/netapp/ontap/cmdref/man1/na_netstat.1.htm) seems to be able to display the information but is not the netstat version available in centos 6.5.

I guess that:

```
head -n1 < /proc/net/tcp ; grep -a 3952364802 /proc/net/tcp
```

allow me to find all state information about a given socket (if `3952364802` is a socket number), but I don't know how to decode its output.

- question: how to see offload state of a given socket?
- bonus question: where can I find description of the heuristic related to offload activation.

Comment: I thought certain operations were offloaded, according to network card capabilities, not specific connections.